# Email Message File Extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, upload

I've got a web application where users are uploading emails and then managers log into an admin view to look at the emails.  We're using IIS7 and ASP.NET 3.5SP1.  I had .msg files set to open in Outlook, but came across another file type today: olk14Message.  Does anyone have a good list of file extensions for emails that I can setup the mimetypes for?

Comment: Outlook ".msg" is the same as MIME format ?

Answer (score 0):

The only extension I'm aware of is .EML.  .MSG is unlikely to be an email, AFAIK.  e.g. it's used for native Windows message information.  I'm pretty sure each email program is different.  olk14Message is an example of Outlook picking an extension on the Mac for it's data.